# CouchDB crashes on startup?

Tags: couchdb

I've installed couchDB in various ways but every time, when I try to run it, I get this crash report and I can't understand what the problem is...

I've installed it on a latest version kUbuntu.Any help?

Error report :

> {"init terminating in
>   do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{error,eacces}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,56}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Comment: Is maybe a CouchDB instance already running and bind to the same port?

Comment: Nope, not running it anywhere else...

Answer (score 3):

`eacces` means invalid file permissions. Follow the [installation guides](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/unix.html#security-considerations) to set them right.

Comment: Error:
Warning: The home dir /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
The system user `couchdb' already exists. Exiting.

Comment: It runs when I do "sudo couchdb"

Comment: Right. Never use sudo to run services. Let your init system do that right for the special user.